# How to make Icon and Text align Left side on JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I want to make text and icon align lift side only
here is the code

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LeftSide
{
public LeftSide()
{
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("submit.gif")));
panel.add(button);
frame.add(panel);
frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
new LeftSide();
}
```

}

if i run this code i will get icon and text on button on center of button so how to make them left side;

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's time to accept the solutions from some of your questions..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To align the text to the left use `button.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);`

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LeftSide
{
    public LeftSide()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("submit.gif")));
        button.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new LeftSide();
    }
}
```

Comment: @krato: Maybe you want to edit your answer. Just for the case someone else starts its Swing UI development from here. Use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new LeftSide());` to make sure everything is done within `EventDispatchThread` as it should. Just a thought, not a must have.

Answer (score 2):

`JButton` is derived from `AbstractButton` which provides a method `setHorizontalAlignment(int)` which should do exactly what you want. Use e.g. `SwingConstants.LEFT` or `SwingConstants.LEADING` to have a left alignment of icon and text.
Give the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setHorizontalAlignment%28int%29) a try to find out more.

Comment: @ShimbuGowda, if it is working then you should "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: sorry i didn't know that, now i did, once again thank you